# Bash Scripting " [!: not found " errors, and how to write an or statement

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, syntax-error

EDIT:
Here is my updated code:

```
#!/bin/sh
files=`ls`
if [ $# -ne 1 -o -f $1 ]
then
        echo "Usage: $0 <directory>"
        exit 1
fi
if [ ! -e $1 ]
then
        echo "$1 not found"
        exit 1

elif [ -d $1 ]
then
cd $1

for f in $files
do
        if [ ! -d "$f" ]
        then
           if [ ! -s "$f" ]
            then
              rm -r "$f"
        echo "File: $f was removed."
        else
        continue
        fi
fi
done


echo "Name\t\tLinks\t\tOwner\t\tDate"

for f in $files
        do
                find "$f" -type f -printf "%f\t\t %n\t\t %u\t %TH %Tb %TY\n"
        done
        exit 0
fi
```

I fixed all of the spacing issues, changed #!bin/sh to #/bin/bash, and added quotes to "$f". However I'm still getting lots of errors.

> ava@kosh:~/test$ ./delDir d1 rm:
>   cannot remove `d1': No such file or
>   directory File: d1 was removed. rm:
>   cannot remove`delDir': No such file
>   or directory File: delDir was removed.
>   rm: cannot remove `delDir2': No such
>   file or directory File: delDir2 was
>   removed. rm: cannot remove`e1': No
>   such file or directory File: e1 was
>   removed. rm: cannot remove `e2': No
>   such file or directory File: e2 was
>   removed. rm: cannot remove`make_d1':
>   No such file or directory File:
>   make_d1 was removed.
>   Name\t\tLinks\t\tOwner\t\tDate find:
>   d1: No such file or directory find:
>   delDir: No such file or directory
>   find: delDir2: No such file or
>   directory find: e1: No such file or
>   directory find: e2: No such file or
>   directory find: make_d1: No such file
>   or directory ne1              2
>   ava       22 Nov 2009 ne2
>   2               ava       22 Nov 2009

Does anyone know what else I'm doing wrong?

> <s>Here's my code:</s>
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> files=`ls`
> if [ $# -ne 1 ]
> then
>         echo "Usage: $0 <directory>"
>         exit 1
> fi
> if [ ! -e $1 ]
> then
>         echo "$1 not found"
>         exit 1
>
> elif [ -d $1 ]
> then
> cd $1
>
> for f in $files
> do
>         if [! -d $f]
>         then
>            if [ ! -s $f ]
>             then
>               rm-r $f
>         echo "File: $f was removed."
>         else
>         continue
>         fi
> fi
> done
>
>
> echo "Name\t\tLinks\t\tOwner\t\tDate"
>
> for f in $files
>         do
>                 find $f -type f -printf "%f\t\t %n\t\t %u\t %TH %Tb %TY\n"
>         done
>         exit 0
> fi
> ```
>
> Here are my questions:
>
> 1. If I execute the script with something that is NOT an ordinary file
>      AND  is NOT a directory I want it to
>      say "Usage: Filename directory" (see
>      line 5). I know I can do this with 2
>      if statements but is it possible to
>      create an or statement for this in
>      bash?
> 2. When I run the script I keep getting errors like this:
>
> > ./delDir: 39: [!: not found ./delDir: 39: [!: not found ./delDir:
> >     39: [!: not found ./delDir: 39: [!:
> >     not found ./delDir: 39: [!: not found
> >     ./delDir: 39: [!: not found ./delDir:
> >     39: [!: not found ./delDir: 39: [!:
> >     not found ./delDir: 39: [!: not found
> >     ./delDir: 39: [!: not found Name
> >     Links           Owner           Date
> >     find: d1: No such file or directory
> >     find: delDir: No such file or
> >     directory find: delDir2: No such file
> >     or directory e1               1
> >     ava       22 Nov 2009 e2
> >     1               ava       22 Nov 2009
> >     find: make_d1: No such file or
> >     directory ne1              2
> >     ava       22 Nov 2009 ne2
> >     2               ava       22 Nov 2009
>
> I believe I am getting these errors
>   because the for loop is first looking
>   for the file that the user typed in
>   (the directory it changed into) and
>   cannot find it. How can if fix this?
>   3. Are there any more errors you can see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another issue is that at the start of the script you do

```
files = `ls`
```

but then you cd to a different directory and try to loop round $files deleting them - of course this will not work since you have changed directories.

move the ls line to after you have changed directory.

Comment: Ah... okay I see. I'm trying that now.

Answer (score 12):

You forgot to put a space after `[` and before `]` on the line saying:

```
if [! -d $f]
```

AND tests are created using `-a`, `-o` is equal to OR:

```
if [ ! -d $f -a -f $f ]
if [ ! -d $f -o -f $f ]
```

Comment: Here's what happens after the spaces have been removed:
ava@kosh:~/test$ ./delDir d1
./delDir: 39: rm-r: not found
File: d1 was removed.
./delDir: 39: rm-r: not found
File: delDir was removed.
./delDir: 39: rm-r: not found
File: delDir2 was removed.
./delDir: 39: rm-r: not found
File: e1 was removed.
./delDir: 39: rm-r: not found
File: e2 was removed.
./delDir: 39: rm-r: not found
File: make_d1 was removed.
Name            Links           Owner           Date
find: d1: No such file or directory
find: delDir: No such file or directory
find: delDir2: No such file or directory
e1               1

Comment: You need to add a space between the `rm` and the `-r`; bash sees this a command `rm-r` and not `rm -r`.

Answer (score 5):

Try putting a space between the `[` and `!`.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct, here's why: [ is a command. If you type "[!", the shell looks for a command by that name.

Answer (score 2):

I'm augmenting other answers here ... every time I see a bash question start with `#! /bin/sh` I have to jump in, its a moral imperative.

Keep in mind that `/bin/sh` points to the POSIX invocation of bash, or a completely different "posixically correct" shell like dash. /bin/sh is often a symbolic link that causes bash to alter its behavior to be more POSIX compliant. Hence, lots of goodies won't work as usual, or you may find your code being parsed by another shell.

In other words, /bin/sh == [POSIX_ME_HARDER](http://www.wlug.org.nz/POSIX_ME_HARDER), but .. yikes! `==` is a [bashism](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-motu/2008-April/003724.html) :)

If you want bash, use `#!/bin/bash`

Beyond that, singingwolfboy's answer should fix your immediate problem :)

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the tip, I'll have to use that.

Answer (score 1):

The others got the spacing issue with the `[`, but I noticed a couple other things.

You probably need a space in your `rm` command in line 23:

```
rm -r $f
```

Also, it's usually good practice to double quote file paths.  This will allow your script to handle filenames with spaces and other special characters correctly.

```
rm -r "$f"
```

Comment: Thanks for the info Amrox, I added the quotes as per your suggestion. I'll have to make use of them in the future.